# How to push two different data in an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic-arrays

I'm working with react and I want to add two types of data in an array.
Here, the getSource function is triggering twice with two different values but in the getSource function it's storing only the first value which is pushed in the accountFeeDetails, I tried using let in the place of const but it's not working.

Please suggest any other way to do it. Thanks

```js
export const selectFeeFundingValue = createSelector(
  [selectedDrawdownAccount, selectAccountInContext, selectFeeFunding],
  (drawdownAccount, pensionAccount, feeFunding) => {
    const drawdown = Object.values(feeFundingValue) ? .find(
      (item) => item.accountNumber === drawdownAccount.accountNumber
    );
    const pension = Object.values(feeFunding) ? .find(
      (item) => item.accountNumber === pensionAccount.accountNumber
    );

    const drawdownFeeValue = getSource(drawdown);
    const pensionFeeValue = getSource(pension);

    return {
      drawdownFeeValue,
      pensionFeeValue
    }
  }
)


//getSource Function
export const getSource = (account) => {
  const accountFeeDetails = [];
  const {
    feeFunding
  } = account || {};

  if (feeFunding) {
    const firstItem = feeFunding[0];

    accountFeeDetails.push({
      type: 'FEE',
      value: getMethod(firstItem)
    });
    accountFeeDetails.push({
      type: 'SOURCE',
      value: firstItem.source.id
    })
  }
  return accountFeeDetails;
};


 //input to getSource function
  { feeFunding: [ {...}, {...} ], accountNumber: "AP100108" }
  { feeFunding: [ {...}, {...} ], accountNumber: "AP107159" }

 //output of getSource function
  [ {type: "FEE", value: "DEFAULT"}, 
    {type: "SOURCE", value: "AP100108"} ]
 //I'm getting the same output twice
```

Comment: Can you describe the result data and its inputs?

Comment: I have added the inputs and outputs, please have a look

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code and I tried your code, it worked.

Comment: Are you getting two different outputs?

Comment: Setting accountFeeDetails as a const is right?